Como separo el #include <stdio.h> del margen superior?
he probado codeblocks en varias distros linux y al escribir el #include <stdio.h>, solo con el tipo de letra Nimbus Mono PS Regular sale pegado al margen de arriba, es molesto alguien sabe como solucionar por favor.
